# No logro limitar días en jtextfield

Tags: java

Ya lo limité a dos dígitos pero ahora quiero que esté entre 1 y 31 (para el mes).
Código:

```
    // codigo para validar cantidad de digitos (maximo 2 digitos)
    int numero = 2;//declaramos la cantidad de digitos
    if (txtdias.getText().length() >= numero) {// maximo 2 digitos
        evt.consume();
    }
    // Validamos caja de texto solo numerico
    String s1 = String.valueOf(evt.getKeyChar());
    if (!(s1.matches("[1-9_0]"))) {
        evt.consume();
    }
```

Comment: Ruberth, por favor no utilices imágenes a menos que sea necesario. Te pido que edites tu pregunta y agregues tu código como texto. Describe mejor el problema actual y el resultado esperado.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien qué estás haciendo pero creo que te estás complicando. Si quieres validar un campo de texto te propongo esto:

```
    String s = txtdias.getText();
    int i = -1;
    try {
        i = Integer.parseInt(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // error - no es numérico
    }
    if (i < 0 || i > 31) {
        // error
    }
```

Si tienes otras exigencias - avisa. Pero luego vas a tener problemas con los meses... en fin, tu sabrás.

Comment: Allí estás haciendo una doble escritura del valor de tu variable `i` si es un número y una escritura de valor si no es un número. Evita inicializar variables si no sabes su valor.

Comment: Tiene su "por qué".Inicializo la variable a **-1**, así está lista para la comprobación del rango 0-31. Qué hay que hacer si no es numérico es cosa del desarrollador, no conozco la lógica de su aplicación.

Comment: no es un error de lógica, es un error de optimización, si asignas el valor de `-1` en el catch funcionará más rápidamente.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes resolver el error utilizando un JSpinner en vez de un JTextField,
el JSpinner quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
 private javax.swing.JSpinner numeroSpinner;
 numeroSpinner = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
 numeroSpinner.setModel(new javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel(1, 1, 31, 1));
```

O podrías hacerlo manualmente sin código entrando a las propiedades del JSpinner y modificar la propiedad llamada **model**, y cambiar los parámetros para que te quede de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]